# Execute Files in Directory With A Delay

Tags: batch-file

I need to run a batch file that goes through 700+ files in a directory and executes them one after another....but with a 3 minute delay. All the files have the same extension, but different file names. So it would execute the first file.....sleep for 3 minutes....then run the next file in the directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a normal loop and use `timeout` to wait:

```
for %%x in (*.extension) do (
  start %%x
  timeout /t 180 /nobreak >nul
)
```

Answer (score 0):

What man page did you get that one.  Kind of funny specifying options with forward strokes (which are used in path names)...

I think you mean;

```
for x in (*.extension); do 
  ./$(x);
  timeout 180 > /dev/null;
done
```

Comment: No, it is kind of funny that you did not realize this question is about a Windows batch file, not a Unix script. It isn't stated explicitly in the question, but the one and only tag is very specific to Windows batch files.

Comment: Batch-file: to me the word batch reminds me of batch processing, as opposed to interactive processing (with a real human operator).  If the script reads input from a file, and has the output and error streams redirected it is batch processing, especially if the script was executed with nohup, and the user logs out of the system.  Please tell me how someone with absolutely no MS Windows experience possibly be able to surmise that this is windows specific.  Since Unix is the lingua franca of computer science, how are we to know that it is in fact specific to MS Windows.